# IndexOutOfBounds : Invalid Index 0, Size is 0

Tags: android

I have this code, which giving `Exception`:

```
IndexOutOfBound :Invalid Index 0, Size is 0
```

Here's my code:

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> vehlist;
 HashMap<String, String> vehmap;

 for(int i = 0;i<BackgroundService.taxis.size();i++){
                vehmap = new HashMap<String, String >();
                vehmap.put("vehno", BackgroundService.taxis.get(i));
                vehmap.put("vehmotion",BackgroundService.taximoving.get(i)+"");
                vehmap.put("vehpanic", BackgroundService.ppanic.get(i)+"");
                vehmap.put("vehpower", BackgroundService.ppower.get(i)+"");
                vehlist.add(vehmap);
            }
```

Here I adding data

```
     if(activestatus){////////////activation
       String taxinos= tokens.nextToken();
       StringTokenizer tokentaxi = new StringTokenizer(taxinos, ",");
       int taxicount = tokentaxi.countTokens();

     if(taxicount>0){
            taxicount = BackgroundService.taxis.size();///////addded to combat error prone value
            int jj=0;
            for(int i=0;i<taxicount;i++){

             String tax = tokentaxi.nextToken(); 
             StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(tax, ";");
             int taxidetailcount = tok.countTokens();
             if(taxidetailcount==5){
                 if(tok.hasMoreTokens())
                     BackgroundService.taxis.set(jj,tok.nextToken());//was add without index
                 if(tok.hasMoreTokens())
                     BackgroundService.taxitype.set(jj,tok.nextToken());
                 if(tok.hasMoreTokens())
                     BackgroundService.taximoving.set(jj,Boolean.parseBoolean(tok.nextToken().toLowerCase()));//////////added new
                 if(tok.hasMoreTokens())
                     BackgroundService.ppanic.set(jj,Boolean.parseBoolean(tok.nextToken().toLowerCase()));//////////added new
                 if(tok.hasMoreTokens())
                     BackgroundService.ppower.set(jj,Boolean.parseBoolean(tok.nextToken().toLowerCase()));//////////added new


            }
             else{
                 Log.e("Service", "got taxi less value="+i+" ->"+taxidetailcount);
             }
             Log.w("Service", "got taxi "+i+" ->"+tax);
         }
```

I have a backgroundService in which all these are initialized

```
 static List<String> taxis,taxitype,taxifull;
 static List<Boolean> taximoving,ppanic,ppower;
 //Messenger mclients = null; 
  ArrayList<Messenger> mClients = new ArrayList<Messenger>(); 



    taxis = new ArrayList<String>();
    taxitype = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    taxifull = new ArrayList<String>();
    taximoving = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    ppanic = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
    ppower = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
```

Comment: One of your collections: taximoving, ppanic, ppower isn't initialized or contains no element. Are you sure all of them are of the same size?

Comment: post your full code,i think you are not properly intializing collections.

Comment: all these are initialized in a another Java file i.e. BackgroundService

Comment: But where are you adding data to them?

Answer (score 0):

Your collections are empty because the loop that's supposed to fill the data doesn't run and that's because you overwrite the loop counter here

```
 if(taxicount > 0) { // Say, taxicount is 10
        taxicount = BackgroundService.taxis.size();
        // Now, taxicount is 0
        int jj = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < taxicount; i++) { // data loop won't run now
```

Comment: I getting exception in     vehmap.put("vehpanic", BackgroundService.ppanic.get(i)+"");
                vehmap.put("vehpower", BackgroundService.ppower.get(i)+"");
                vehlist.add(vehmap);
            }

Comment: Please pick any good Java book and go over List.size(), add() and set(). You'll begin to understand the issue here. There has to be something inside the list before you set() or get() from it.